# how to draw circle with text in middle and an image as a background of the circle?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I'd like to know that how to draw a circle with text in middle and an image as a background?

This image should be the background of the circle

I have tried to put the image but its not getting the complete background image, only getting a part of image as a background.

```css
#circle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #2098D1;
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url("http://7bna.net/images/background-wallpapers/background-wallpapers-9.jpg");
}
```

```html
<div id="circle"> Hello </div>
```

ww.intrawallpaper.com/static/images/abstract-mosaic-background.png

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a [**Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and _**effort**_.

Comment: Have you tried anything before?

Comment: @Yong Quan I have tried but its not getting desireable result

Comment: @ZunairaZafar see my answer below

Comment: @ZunairaZafar As simple as adding `background-size`. You can read the full stackoverflow documentation via the link in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#circle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #2098D1;
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url("http://intrawallpaper.com/static/images/abstract-mosaic-background.png");
  background-size: 150% 150%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 97% 75%;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle"> Hello </div>
```

You can use `background-position` to adjust the background display area.

Learn more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp).

Alternatively, you can use `background-size: contain` combine with `background-position: center`.

Answer (score 0):

### Background Sizing

Add the appropriate `background-size` and you get your desired outcome.

```css
#circle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #2098D1;
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url("http://intrawallpaper.com/static/images/abstract-mosaic-background.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle"> Hello </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is working fiddle link:
https://jsfiddle.net/ash06229/jckyk3cr/

```
.circle {
  background: url(http://www.intrawallpaper.com/static/images/abstract-mosaic-background.png);
    background-size: cover;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
    color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple HTML/CSS. Read from w3school or google it.

HTML:

```
<div class="writeOver">
    Some Text
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.writeOver{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 50px;
    background-image: url('/path/to/image/bg.png')
}
```

You can adjust accordingly.